# The differentiability of the complex valued function $(Rez)(Imz)z\over|z|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, limits, complex-numbers

$$
f(z) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \Re(z)\Im(z)z\over|z|^2 & \quad z \neq 0 \\
            0 & \quad z = 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
I want to prove that this function is not complex differentiable at 0 but not sure what sort of an approach should be taken. Hope someone could assist me on this. Thanks

Comment: Compute the difference quotient $\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}$ if $z$ is real. You get $0$. Then compute it when $z= h+ih$. Is the limit $0$ as $h \to 0$?